# "USB Device is locked" when trying to backup system

Tags: ps3

I insert a USB drive into my PS3, go to settings --> system settings --> backup utility, click through the screens, choose my USB drive... and it tells me "USB Drive is locked."

- There is no physical locking mechanism on the drive
- I've tried reformatting as FAT32
- I've tried different allocation unit sizes, as suggested [here](http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-Network-General/Newbie-Question/td-p/3021401).
- The drive can be read fine by the PS3, and read/written to fine by a PC.

Information on the net is sparse - has anyone had similar problems?  The USB drive is an HP.

Comment: Some games have copy protection on it that will prevent you from moving them. What brand is you USB drive? Certain drivers aren't compatible with console gaming systems

Comment: @Krazer: I am not copying any specific game-saves, I am using the system backup utility.  I mention the brand in the question.

Comment: How large is the USB drive. If I remember correctly, the system backup can require several GB of data.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I use a USB drive that is as large as what I have installed on my PS3's HDD it will give me the same error. You should uninstall games if you can just install them again easily. I deleted my games from a 500gb HDD so that I only had save data, and it allowed me to use a 120gb drive for backup.  I don't understand why it does that though, because when using the backup utility I've never had it actually back up the installed games anyway.